# Trigger snackbar message on page load in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and trying to trigger a snack bar on page load if a message was returned from the page I navigated from. I have managed to get the message to display on a button click, but get an error stating that my context does not have a Scaffold if I try to do it elsewhere.

I am also struggling to find an example of how to show a sack bar without user interaction, so if anyone has a reference, that would surely go a long way in helping as well.

Here is a simplified version of my view:

```
class LandingView extends StatefulWidget {
  final LandingViewModel viewModel;

  LandingView(this.viewModel);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _ViewState();
  }
}

class _ViewState extends State<LandingView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _showSnackbar(context, message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    );
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          },
          child: _buildLayout(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLayout(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> args = getArgs(context); //get value from previous page

    if (args != null &&
        args["Toast Message"] != null) //check if a value was returned from the previous page. This has been tested and a valid string is being returned
      _showSnackbar(
          context, args["Toast Message"]); //if so call snack bar function
// this throws an error saying "Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold"

    return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints boxConstraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: boxConstraints.maxHeight),
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                "Show Snack Bar",
              ),
              onPressed: 
                  () {
                if (args != null &&
                    args["Toast Message"] !=
                        null) //check if a value was returned from the previous page. This has been tested and a valid string is being returned
                  _showSnackbar(context,
                      args["Toast Message"]); //if so call snack bar function
                  //this works perfectly
              }),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that because your `LandingView` widget is not in a `Scaffold`. You can fix this by putting the `LandingView` widget inside a `StatelessWidget` with a `Scaffold` and changing any references to `LandingView` to `LandingViewPage`:

```
class LandingViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LandingView()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DF_. As I said, I am still learning how to use Flutter, so excuse my ignorance if I'm wrong, but I believe I have a scaffold here "@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold("

Comment: No that's inside the context of the widget. Your code is asking for the Scaffold above it. Please try the suggestion, you'll find it works.

Comment: If you want to use the context of your ViewState Scaffold then you'll have to use it's global key and get the reference from that. But I think it's easier and cleaner to move the Scaffold to a parent widget.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) method

```
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => scaffold.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("snackbar")));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a stateful widget put:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("Error")));
  });
}
```